# Magento 2: Datetime picker issue

Tags: magento2.3.3

I have added a date-time picker in my custom form using the below code.

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="" class="datepicker">
<script>
    require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          showMonthAfterYear: false,
          dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: '2000:2020',
        })
    });
</script>
```

Also, I have added timezone selection with the date picker. It's showing a fine date and time picker but when I click on the Now button it's giving the incorrect time.

For example, I have selected the IST timezone and click on the Now button and the current IST time is 5:00:00 PM, but the date-timer picker always returns 30 minutes before time than the current time. Datetime returns 4:30:00 AM which is Pacific Standard Time which is set in the Locale of configuration in admin.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Add Input filed and JS code to your form, You can show the current time and select a specific time using the DateTime picker widget.

```
<input type="text" name="datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker" value="" class="datetimepicker">
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/calendar'
], function($){
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showsTime: true
    });
});
</script>
```